# How to assign and call a variable to/from a button

Tags: ios, swift, variables, button, viewcontroller

I'm trying to assign a variable to a button and call up that variable to pass it to another viewcontroller.

Currently I'm sending a title of a button like this:

```
((sender as! UIButton).titleLabel?.text)!
```

But I have a button that I want to send a string to another viewcontroller that is different from its title. I tried adding something in the "label" spot in the identity inspector, but it doesn't seem to be the right way to go.

Any advice is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: can you add more code or function from where you are passing text to mother viewcontroller

Comment: I'm all set in terms of sending information from one viewcontroller to another, I just need to know how to assign a value/label/variable/anything to the button so I can call it up to send. My code currently sends the title of the button, I just want to know how to send something else.

Comment: "how to assign a value/label/variable/anything to the button" part is bit unclear, are you want to pass the string to next viewcontroller so that you can set the text of the button?

Comment: Yes, I want to pass a string to the next viewcontroller to set the text of a button on that viewcontroller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a outlet to the button in next ViewController and also add one string variable and set the title using the method `setTitle(_ title: String?, for state: UIControlState)` in viewDidLoad

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    var buttonText: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let buttonText = buttonText {
            button.setTitle(buttonText, for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
```

and in FirstViewController assign the text to the string variable in SecondVC like below

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "CustomSegue", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "CustomSegue" {
            let vc = segue.destination as? SecondViewController
            vc?.buttonText = "ButtonTitle"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for passing the button title, you can have sender as a type of UIButton rather than Any so that you can send buttonTitle using  sender.titleLabel?.text

Answer (score 1):

Store the variable elsewhere in the class and set the didSet annotation like this

```
var myTitle: String{
didSet{
self.theDesiredButton.setTitle(myTitle, for: .normal)
//alternatively you can use 
self.theDesiredButton.title = myTitle
     }

}
```

and here pass variable to another controller:

```
override func prepareForSegue(/*dunno args I code from mobile*/){
//guess figure out segueIdentifier and desired Vc subclass
if let myCustomVC = segue.viewContoller as? CustomVCSubclass{
myCustomVC.valueToPass = self.myTitle
}
}
```

or you can instantiet viewController with identifier as your subclassed VC and pass the value the same way

```
func pushNextVC(){
if let newVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(with: "identifierFromIB") as? CustomVCSubclass{
newVC.valueToPass = self.myTitle
self.NavigationController.push(newVC)
}
 }
```

For any questions ask :) wish happy coding